# CartoDB "Error loading rows, check your SQL query" & "There is a pb with your connection"

Tags: postgis, carto

I have been trying to install my own CartoDB server for a few weeks.

I succeeded to install each part with no error (after few corrections) with [this tutorial](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb).
Make check with CartoDB-SQL-API and Windshaft-CartoDB are ok!

I can import data : when I am in my dashboard, I can see my file with its 193 rows.

But when I try to see the table, the message "**Error loading rows, check your SQL query**" appears.
All columns of my file are here but empty.

I try to click on Map View, which give me the following error : "**There is a problem with your connection**".

The view is already focused on the area which contains my data.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue while forgotting to change the variable module.exports.node_host    in my development environment file from '127.0.0.1' to 'development.localhost.lan'.

I am not using the service from the server itself (localhost), so this was preventing the CartoDBSqlApi work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Following setting should fix this problem.

change tiler_port, sql_port in your app_config.yml to"8181", "8080" respectively.

```
tiler_port:    "8181"
sql_port:     "8080"
```

And  `host` in windshaft and `module.exports.node_host` in sql-api config files to empty.

`host: ‘’`

`module.exports.node_host: ‘’` // so the tiler and sql api listens to all IP address